# Abandoned cart email is not sending to customer

Tags: magento-1.9, module, email

we are using [custom module](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/abandoned-carts-notifications-1.html) for sending abandoned cart email to customers.

cron job is working fine in site as checked with AOE extenison.
 as in configuration , i waited for more than one day but still i didt got any abandoned cart email.

[image]

for checking module is working or not, i followed :

```
Set Dry Run to Yes
Set Test email to your test customer email
logged in as your test customer, add a product to your cart and log out
Go back to the backend in the module configuration page and click on the Send button
```

when i checked the `/var/log/digitalpianism_abandonedcarts.log` file, i found as below :

```
2016-07-04T11:13:37+00:00 DEBUG (7): DigitalPianism_Abandonedcarts_Model_Observer::_sendEmailssendAbandonedCartsEmail: kidsdial11@gmail.com
2016-07-04T11:13:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): DigitalPianism_Abandonedcarts_Model_Observer::_sendEmailssendAbandonedCartsEmail: kidsdial101@gmail.com
2016-07-04T11:13:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): DigitalPianism_Abandonedcarts_Model_Observer::_sendEmailssendAbandonedCartsEmail: kidsdial17@gmail.com
```

**controllers**

```
<?php

/**
 * Class DigitalPianism_Abandonedcarts_Adminhtml_AbandonedcartsController
 */
class DigitalPianism_Abandonedcarts_Adminhtml_AbandonedcartsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    /**
     * Check for is allowed
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('system/config/abandonedcartsconfig');
    }

    /**
     * Manually send the notifications
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendAction()
    {
        $model = Mage::getModel('abandonedcarts/observer');
        $model->sendAbandonedCartsEmail(true);
        $model->sendAbandonedCartsSaleEmail();

        $result = 1;
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setBody($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: We're working on a new improved version of the module that'll be out this week, I'll keep in touch with you ;)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Thats nice to hear that, but if it possible to help me for this one, that will be great as i am struggling for this from last one week with many modules and none of module is working for me.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism As i saw in reviwes section, this extensions worked for many. so i guess somewhere i am missing.

Comment: Yes usually people are having this problem because their cron is not properly configured but it is not your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you get the following in the log file:

```
2016-07-04T11:13:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): DigitalPianism_Abandonedcarts_Model_Observer::_sendEmailssendAbandonedCartsEmail: kidsdial17@gmail.com
```

That means this code has been called:

```
                Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                    ->sendTransactional(
                        $templateId,
                        $sender,
                        $email,
                        $recipient['emailTemplateVariables']['fullname'] ,
                        $recipient['emailTemplateVariables'],
                        null);
```

So the problem is either that your `kidsdial17@gmail.com` email address has not received the email (check your spam folder) or your email server did not send the email (check your email error logs).

Comment: we are using `smtp pro extension` to send mails and all emails like order , customer registration emails are working fine.
even i checked with different email ids, but no email id got abandoned cart email. also i checked in spam folder also.

Comment: @BabyinMagento try to create a custom abandoned cart transactional email template and assign it in the configuration

Comment: okay , i created `custom abandoned cart transactional email template` and set the same in configuration. is i need to wait for 24 hours ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento you can click the send button it will override the delay and send every abandoned carts immediately

Comment: I did that , now in log folder its updated as this with new timings : `2016-07-04T11:13:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): DigitalPianism_Abandonedcarts_Model_Observer::_sendEmailssendAbandonedCartsEmail: a@3.com` but no email sent to test email id.

Comment: @BabyinMagento hang on, do you have an email inbox that corresponds to a@3.com ? If you want to receive the email it needs to be a real email address you've got access to.

Comment: this is complete var file, please check  : http://pasted.co/91902559, here some have email id created and some are not , i checked in emaild id that are created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42315/discussion-between-raphael-at-digital-pianism-and-baby-in-magento).

Comment: Sorry dear, i wasted your time yesterday..... it was problem with smtp extension.

Comment: @BabyinMagento glad you worked it out =)